# Reactive support for CMIS

Tags: spring-webflux, cmis

I'm working with file storage systems (IBM FileNet, Alfresco) via CMIS (Content Management Interoperability Services), browser binding, using the Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS library.

This library sends blocking http calls to the CMIS server. My app is build on Spring WebFlux, and blocking calls are bad for Reactor Netty's event loop.

Are there any reactive libraries in Java/Kotlin for working with CMIS? Maybe someone made a homebrew side project? Or should I just write my own, based on Spring WebClient?

Also, it kinda seems like CMIS isn't very popular these days. What is used for content management and file storage in reactive apps these days?

Comment: What do you mean by a reactive library?

Comment: Basically a library that returns objects wrapped in a Mono/Flux (or another compatible type of Publisher)